# Adding GamerServicesComponent causes ridiculously long program start

Tags: xna-4.0, xname

Having finished the prototype for a game I'm working on, I moved on to integrate Networking and Netcode. The whole thing works fine aswell, my only problem is that upon adding the GamerServicesComponent to the Game, it takes forever to startup. It compiles just fine in a reasonable amount of time, but starting the application itself takes anywhere from between 5-60 seconds (at least I haven't waited longer than that since I decided to quit at that point). Before adding the Component, startup time was between 0.25 and 0.5 seconds.

I read about a possible problem with multicore AMD processors (I'm using an X4 Phenom), but that post was from 2008. I tried the possible solution of installing the AMD Multicore Tool, but that didn't change a bit. I'm not even sure that's causing my problem.

Aside from the above, I didn't find ANYTHING on the Interwebs regarding this topic, so my hopes of getting an answer to this problem are relatively low.
Also, why is XNA so incredibly bad documented? It seems that only a handfull of people use this technology.